# use in php/mysql table multiple join as object or something similar

Tags: php, mysql, join

In my mysql db I have a "4 level parent table" and when I use them in php I wouldn't like to write everytime the multiple join...
**Example**

```
select ... FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB ON (tableA.id = tableB.idA) INNER 
JOIN tableC ON (tableB.id = tableC.idB)...
```

Comment: done using CREATE VIEW

Comment: beware than when querying the view for a particular value, it may happen that the optimizer decides to run the entire view, and then query it for your value. Stored procedure will do exactly what you tell it. The performance difference can be significant. It's like select * from (select* from table) where condition VS select * from table where condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I use them in php I wouldn't like to write everytime the multiple
>   join.

Consider creating a `VIEW` then with your query like below and use that view in `PHP` code

```
create view vw_multilevelquery as
select ... FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB ON (tableA.id = tableB.idA) 
INNER JOIN tableC ON (tableB.id = tableC.idB)...
```

In your `PHP` code just perform a `SELECT` on created view like

```
select * from vw_multilevelquery;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using stored procedures as shorthand for queries with variables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

The benefit over using a view is full use of the WHERE filter.

When querying a view, the optimiser may decide to do

```
select * from (select ... from ...) where col=value
```

while when using a stored procedure, you will have

```
select ... from ... where col=value
```

the performance difference may be significant.